# Postfix relaying via specific outgoing IP

Tags: email, configuration, postfix-mta

I've been pulling my hair getting this to work but i have a problem with the sender_dependent_default_transport_maps:

Sending a mail via the specific postfix works like it should the correct outgoing transport is used. But when the situation is as follows:
externally received mail from somewhere (external@gmail.com) to my local (virtual) address (local@local.com) which should forward to i.e. final-destination@gmail.com doesnt get routed using the sender_dependent_default_transport_maps...

i.e. i've configured local.com to use a specific IP. Logging into the server and sending it directly works... BUT when when deliverying a relayed mail the transport is ignored...

Is there a way to adhere to the sender_dependent_default_transport_maps when relaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around my question: by rearranging the eth-configs i've managed to change the default outgoing IP for relayed mail...

Sigh...